# how to manage requests in a queue to a Flask server?

Tags: html, flask, flask-wtforms

I am working on building a simple Flask server which is going to provide a compilation service to a small group of people.

One can connect to the server using a url, enter his function code to a `</textarea>` and then hit a "`submit`" button that is going to compile the code in the background and then display it on another `</textarea>` on the same page.
Each such compilation request might take few minutes, so I was thinking that I will need some queue to store those users' requests in case some users are making requests simultaneously. 
What is the best way to do that? Should I create a `Lib/Queue` and manage everything manually, the queueing the callback afterwards and so forth?

I assume there is some know methodology for queueing such requests made to a server which is simply don't know. I don't think i need to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: What about using Redis or RabbitMQ?

Comment: It's possible I just don't know. I see there is http://flask-and-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, maybe that's a good starting point.

Comment: Is that a good assumption that any similar server which does something kinda similar, doing some background operation upon each request and then providing back a reply, must be using some queue management like Redis/RabbitMQ/... ? I wanna make sure I am indeed think right about it.

Comment: Yes it is. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `celery` to do task queue as async [task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this on single request. Cause it will be timeout before the process is done.
You need to use queue mechanism or signaling to used as a queue.

So The idea is that, you need to put the data in another space and doing that process in another process, instead in on single process.

I would suggest you to do like this

1. User request some data say with this url `proccess/data` then flask store the data in somewhere in queue mechanism, and return the `uniqueId` like ticket number.
2. Another process called `worker` is listen whenever any message to be process, if any it should process directly, and the final data store back to the queue.
3. Create another url say `result/<uniqueId>` and this process will check weather any data final available from `worker` with this ID. If any just return that value, otherwise throw error.

For worker we can use whatever, we can even used 2 flask, that will act like producer and consumer. For Advance Queue you can use [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html)

And for storing data, you can use redis, rabbitMQ, or even database.